# Can't Add '/path/to/file' to a parent directory scheduled for deletion

Tags: bash, svn

I've been attempting to use the following script to commit a wordpress plugin to the WP svn repo from my public git repository and keep getting error:

```
svn: E155013: Can't add '/path/to/file' to a parent directory scheduled for deletion
```

Whenever there is a new file, not previously known to `svn`, when adding files, resulting in either an aborted commit, or worse, a broken commit where it commits with missing files.

```
#! /bin/bash
# A modification of Dean Clatworthy's deploy script as found here: https://github.com/deanc/wordpress-plugin-git-svn
# The difference is that this script lives in the plugin's git repo & doesn't require an existing SVN repo.

# main config
PLUGINSLUG="my-plugin-slug"
CURRENTDIR=`pwd`
MAINFILE="my-plugin.php" # this should be the name of your main php file in the wordpress plugin

# git config
GITPATH="$CURRENTDIR/" # this file should be in the base of your git repository

# svn config
SVNPATH="/tmp/$PLUGINSLUG" # path to a temp SVN repo. No trailing slash required and don't add trunk.
SVNURL="http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin" # Remote SVN repo on wordpress.org, with no trailing slash
SVNUSER="wp_username" # your svn username


# Let's begin...
echo ".........................................."
echo 
echo "Preparing to deploy wordpress plugin"
echo 
echo ".........................................."
echo 

# Check if subversion is installed before getting all worked up
#if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' subversion 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") != "1" ]
#then
#   echo "You'll need to install subversion before proceeding. Exiting....";
#   exit 1;
#fi

# Check version in readme.txt is the same as plugin file after translating both to unix line breaks to work around grep's failure to identify mac line breaks
NEWVERSION1=`grep "^Stable tag:" $GITPATH/readme.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $NF}'`
echo "readme.txt version: $NEWVERSION1"
NEWVERSION2=`grep "^ \* Version:" $GITPATH/$MAINFILE | awk -F' ' '{print $NF}'`
echo "$MAINFILE version: $NEWVERSION2"

if [ "$NEWVERSION1" != "$NEWVERSION2" ]; then echo "Version in readme.txt & $MAINFILE don't match. Exiting...."; exit 1; fi

echo "Versions match in readme.txt and $MAINFILE. Let's proceed..."

if git show-ref --tags --quiet --verify -- "refs/tags/$NEWVERSION1"
    then 
        echo "Version $NEWVERSION1 already exists as git tag. Exiting...."; 
        exit 1; 
    else
        echo "Git version does not exist. Let's proceed..."
fi

cd $GITPATH
echo -e "Enter a commit message for this new version: \c"
read COMMITMSG
git commit -am "$COMMITMSG"

echo "Tagging new version in git"
git tag -a "$NEWVERSION1" -m "Tagging version $NEWVERSION1"

echo "Pushing latest commit to origin, with tags"
git push origin master
git push origin master --tags

echo 
echo "Creating local copy of SVN repo ..."
svn co $SVNURL $SVNPATH

echo "Clearing svn repo so we can overwrite it"
svn rm $SVNPATH/trunk/*

echo "Exporting the HEAD of master from git to the trunk of SVN"
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=$SVNPATH/trunk/

echo "Ignoring github specific files and deployment script"
svn propset svn:ignore "deploy.sh
README.md
bower_components
node_modules
.DS_Store
.gitmodules
advanced
assets
gulpfile.js
bower.json
package.json
.git
.gitignore" "$SVNPATH/trunk/"

echo "Changing directory to SVN and committing to trunk"
cd $SVNPATH/trunk/
# Add all new files that are not set to be ignored
echo "Doing the file adding"
# THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
echo "Committing"
svn commit --username=$SVNUSER -m "$COMMITMSG"

echo "Creating new SVN tag & committing it"
cd $SVNPATH
svn copy trunk/ tags/$NEWVERSION1/
cd $SVNPATH/tags/$NEWVERSION1
svn commit --username=$SVNUSER -m "Tagging version $NEWVERSION1"

echo "Removing temporary directory $SVNPATH"
rm -fr $SVNPATH/

echo "*** FIN ***"
```

Could anyone elaborate on what is causing this error and possibly recommend either a different or adapted approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dean's version doesn't contain brainless `svn rm $SVNPATH/trunk/*`

`rm $SVNPATH/trunk/*` *or* checkout with `--depth`+commit with `--set-depth`

Comment: `rm rm $SVNPATH/trunk/*`? Is that a mistype?

Comment: @MikeiLL - just blind misprint , fixed

Comment: i need to check out the `--depth` and `--set-depth` tags. git continues to blow me away. will confirm and select as answer ASAP.

Comment: `--depth` and `--set-depth` are SVN options: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html